# Let $V$ be a finite real vector space, $W$ a subspace. What is the fundamental group of $V-W$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am not sure is this the same with $\Bbb R^n-\Bbb R^m$. Even in this case I am not sure about how to compute the fundamental group. When $n$ and $m$ are less than $3$, everything thing seems OK. But what about $n$ and $m$ larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every finite-dimensional real vector space is linearly homeomorphic to some $\Bbb R^n$, so we do not lose generality in solving the problem for $\Bbb R^n \setminus \Bbb R^m$. Normalization gives that $\Bbb R^n \setminus \Bbb R^m$ is homotopically equivalent to $\Bbb S^{n-m-1}$, so: $$\pi_1(\Bbb R^n \setminus \Bbb R^m) = \begin{cases} \Bbb Z, & \text{if } m = n-2,\\ \{0\}, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks! So could you please explain more about what does normalization mean?

Comment: Sure. I just meant the map: $$\Bbb R^n \setminus \Bbb R^m \ni x \mapsto \frac{x}{\|x\|} \in \Bbb S^{n-m-1}.$$

Comment: Note that $0 \not\in \Bbb R^n \setminus \Bbb R^m$, so we don't have any problems. I do assume we mean that $\Bbb R^m \subset \Bbb R^n$ has the last $n-m$ last entries equal to $0$, etc.

Comment: Geometrically: Project onto the orthogonal complement and then project onto the unit sphere.

Comment: @IvoTerek Very clear, thanks!